# Ist good practice adding Converter Between api and client

Tags: javascript, api, api-design, react

I just want to curious about adding a converter is a good practice or not.

I have multiple API and I always convert API return fields to my client fields.

Like=>

```
function ConvertFromAPI(apidata){        
    var result= new user();       

    if(apidata){   
        result.id = apidata.id;        
        result.username= apidata.username;    
    .
    .
    .
    }    
    return result;
}
```

Why I do like that,

I don't need to care about field names changing in API.

I can add some injection code there.

It's like the way I always did so I want to do it.

But now I start thinking Is it worth to do that or It is really necessary? because If I do that way I have to do two converters like `fromapi` and `toapi` for my object to API object and If API has over 10k record, It would be effective to performance?

And I would like to know how other people do?

Like, use directly the API field to the component?

Comment: Honestly, only if you need it.  If you are simply copying values form one object to identically named values in another object this doesn't provide any value.  However, if an API changes the name of a field, then this would be necessary in that case if you don't want to (or don't have the time to) fix all the places it's used.

Comment: There's an open source library named class-transformer which performs data transformation from plain objects to actual classes. It's usefull to map API responses and transform them into classes. It also reduces the impact in case there's a change on the API response.